# Overloading the << operator with template class

Tags: c++, class, templates, overloading

As the title says I want to overload the << operator with a template class

but keep getting a "does not match any template declaration"

eg. in the .h file

```
template <class T>
class foo
{
friend ostream & operator<< <T>(ostream &output , foo<T> & F);

}
```

and in the .cpp file

```
template <class T>
ostream & operator<< <T>(ostream &output , foo<T> & F)
{

output<<"whatever";

return output;
}
```

How would I possible do that as I'm still learning to this.

Comment: Unrelated, but do you really want to split it into a header and a cpp file? Normally, you put the definition in the headers when dealing with templates.

Comment: @super I have to as it is part of the spec that they gave me for this assignment

Comment: TL;DR: Do like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/qaMWexs1a)

Comment: Templates are like *core language macros*.  They are instantiated when used.  By putting the definition in a `*.cpp` file, the definition won't be automagically instantiated when used.  That's why templates that are shared between translation units go in header files.  (You can put the definition in a `*.cpp` file, but then you have to instantiate it explicitly.  Which is a bother, and fragile.)